# Расширение для chrome: не работает jQuery

Tags: jquery, chrome-extension, расширения, extension

Решил написать расширение для vk.com в chrome. Занятие - проще некуда. В "content_scripts" подключил свой vkc_script.js, который исправно работал на всех "*://vk.com/*".
Однако, потом я решил написать что-нибудь по-серьёзнее, захотел подключить jQuery и появилась проблема:

jQuery на странице есть:

[image: jQuery]
.

но использовать его почему-то не получается: [image: error]

Люди добрые, памагити!

---

**manifest.json:**

```
{
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "VKColor",
      "description": "Color is important.",
      "version": "1.0",
      "content_scripts": [{
          "matches": ["*://vk.com/*"],
          "js": ["/script/vkc_script.js", "/script/jquery.js"],
          "css": ["/script/vkc_style.css"]
      }]
}
```

Если jQuery подключать динамически в vkc_script.js - все в порядке, но этот вариант меня не устраивает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что `jquery.js` подхватывается после `vkc_script.js`

Поэтому, наиболее вероятно, надо просто поменять порядок:

```
"js": ["/script/jquery.js", "/script/vkc_script.js"]
```